# Is it possible to use interpolation in a pipe parameter?

Tags: angular, pipe

I have a pipe like this one:

```
{{ testValue2 | customRound:4 }}
```

I was wondering if I can use interpolation in the parameter so that I can pass a variable value instead of a hardcoded "4".
I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
{{ testValue2 | customRound:{{customParameter}} }}
```

If I cannot use {{}} it is any way to bind the value of the parameter to a varible in the component?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
{{ testValue2 | customRound:customParameter }}
```